# I need help with this following exponential equation

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

$9^x-6^x+4^x-3^x-2^x+1=0$
I have to find the number of real values of $x$ that satisfy the given equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE community @ShivanshNigam. What is your attempt? What did you try??

Comment: Per fewnominal theory, you also get here an analogue of the Descartes rule of signs. So you get 0, 2 or 4 roots. If I did not mangle my memories too heavily.

Comment: I first got x=0 by observation and then tried factoring for other solutions but couldn't get any

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach is to rewrite LHS of a given equation as:
$(3^x-1)^2 - (3^x-1)(2^x-1)+(2^x-1)^2$

Then we can substitute $3^x-1$ with $u$, and $2^x-1$ with $v$, hence we will have:
$u^2 - uv + v^2 =0$.

Above equation is satisfied if and only if $u=v=0 \iff \boxed{x=0}$.

Comment: It is odd that the editor finds maybe the best factorization. Is there a collaboration here with "the new contributor"?

Comment: To @BobDobbs: Thanks for your comment. No such collaboration, I wanted to see some attempts from "the new contributor", but when I saw one answer, I decided to share yet another approach.

Answer (score 0):

With some experimentation, we can factor as follows:
$$(3^x-2^x-1)3^x + (2^x-1)2^x + 1 = 0.$$

For $x>1$, the LHS will certainly be be positive, which doesn't agree with the RHS.

So we can at least rule out all $x>1$.  (Not that one solution is $x = 0$).

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$9^x -6^x+4^x - 3^x-2^x+1 = (3^x-\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2^x - \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{3}{4}(2^x-1)^2 = 0$$

We have $3^x-\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2^x - \frac{1}{2} = 0, 2^x-1 = 0$ and thus $x = 0$.